# Change permissions to a specific user in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: chmod, chown

How can I change the permission (555 or  755) to a user in a specific folder in Ubuntu 12.04.
I used this command, but it didn't work

```
sudo chown -R username:group directory
```

Thanks,

Comment: The details of your question are very ambiguous, but they matter a lot. Please explain as precisely as possible what you. What properties (location, ownership) and function(s) does the folder have?

Comment: 1. Are there subdirectories and files in each folder? 2. Do you want to have the directories accessible to different users with different access attributes? This is an old question but can be made useful.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to change the permissions use this command (755 will grant the owner of the file read, write and execute permissions and read and execute permissions to group and other users ):

```
sudo chmod -R 755 directory
```

If you want to change ownership of a folder and it's subfolders and files

```
sudo chown -R username:usergroup directory
```

If the owner of a file or directory is let's say the user `jofrey` you want to grant him read and write permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R u+rw directory
```

You can learn more about permission numbers and what they mean from this image

[image: Permissions]