# How to give full access to my other user for all files

Tags: permissions, root, restricted-access

When another user logs in to his account, he is unable to access DISKS and other files. He is also admin, but when he tries to open any disk this message shows.

[image]

Comment: The warning says that the other user does not have read access at all to access that disk2 (give him read access it will be fine)

Comment: you can have a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/90339/how-do-i-set-read-write-permissions-my-hard-drives (if you cant do it just comment here)

Comment: you have any video please if you have please send me link

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have

Answer (score 0):

There is  this answer...

[give specific user permission to write to a folder using +w notation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation)

And this answer...

[Change permissions to a specific user in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607149/change-permissions-to-a-specific-user-in-ubuntu-12-04)

...that are very helpful...